# Uncaught reference error function isn't define; trouble with closers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with closures.  I cannot get this function defined without having an error.  it is giving me a reference error, however i am pretty sure i have my function properly defined. the function in question is "calculatePrice" which is the first function i define. here is my jsfiddle:

html:

```
<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Getting A Quote Is Easy</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We'll give you a quote in a few easy steps</h3> <br/>
<p>Just tell us which options are most similar to your home</p>
        <br/>        

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">What Type Of Home Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Type Of Property</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Semi" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Detatched" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Terrace" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Flat" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bathrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="One" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Two" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Three" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>        


    </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do You Have A Cylinder</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

     <label >Do You Have A Cylinder Tank</label>
     <br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="Yes" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="YBR" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes (but needs removing)</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="No" onclick="calculateTotal()" />No</label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Packages Available</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

    <p>standard and premium system specs</p>
    <br/>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                <br/>
                <div id="premPrice"></div>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Enter your details to a get a free survey</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

js:

```
//jQuery time

function calculateTotal()
{

    var boilerPrice = getBoilerSizePrice() + getBedroomSizePrice() + getBathroomSizePrice()  + getTankSizePrice() ;

    //display the result
        var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "total price £"+boilerPrice;

    var divobj2 = document.getElementById('premPrice');
    divobj2.style.display='block';
    divobj2.innerHTML = "Premium price £"+((boilerPrice/100)*120);

}



var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})





 //Property Type array

 var house_prices = new Array();
 house_prices["Semi"]=1029;
 house_prices["Detatched"]=1290;
 house_prices["Terrace"]=1100;
 house_prices["Flat"]=900;

 function getBoilerSizePrice()
{  
    var boilerSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["house"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            boilerSizePrice = house_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return boilerSizePrice;
}




 var tank_prices = new Array();
 tank_prices["Yes"]=500;
 tank_prices["YBR"]=890;
 tank_prices["No"]=0;


 function getTankSizePrice()
{  
    var tankSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["tank"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            tankSizePrice = tank_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return tankSizePrice;
}

 //bedroom number array 

 var bedroom_prices= new Array();
 bedroom_prices["Beds1"]=89;
 bedroom_prices["Beds2"]=94;
 bedroom_prices["Beds3"]=112;
 bedroom_prices["Beds4"]=145;
 bedroom_prices["Beds5"]=169;
 bedroom_prices["Beds6"]=178;



  function getBedroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bedroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bedroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bedroomSizePrice = bedroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bedroomSizePrice;
}

  //bathroom number array
 var bathroom_prices = new Array();
 bathroom_prices["One"]=119;
 bathroom_prices["Two"]=129;
 bathroom_prices["Three"]=140;



function getBathroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bathroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bathroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bathroomSizePrice = bathroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bathroomSizePrice;
}

calculateTotal();




/* ellement for hiding classes
$(".").hide();
*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ej4j8/

Comment: The js in the fiddle is wrapped in a window.load handler, so it's not in scope for the inline click handlers.

Comment: Your form isn't named "boilerform".

Comment: jason p thanks for the comment, but would care to elaboarte a bit more to a newbie?

Comment: @user3641959 The `calculateTotal` function is only visible in the onload function, not globally. But you still need to use the correct form name.

Comment: how can i go about making the onload function gloabal?

Comment: @user3641959 Also note that you're using buttons, not checkboxes, so using the `checked` property is meaningless.

Comment: @user3641959 Don't wrap it up in another function? Although in general, global stuff is bad--but it looks like you're already in over your head, so take it one step at a time. In jsfiddle just define your JS as "No wrap - in <body>" for now.

Comment: @user3641959 Also, if you're using jQuery, why not just use jQuery and skip the manual, low-level JS work?

Comment: @user3641959 Here's a version where the JS doesn't error out (e.g., I fixed the form names, and moved the function declaration). http://jsfiddle.net/Dh2Sy/2/ You'll still need to actually make things work, though.